# TFS Builds - Put several files from other folders to one folder after building

Tags: service, tfs, build

In TFS Builds component I try to do this for instance, to put these files:

- Main\Folder1...\bin\file1.dll
- Main\Folder2...\bin\file2.dll

In one file such as: \Main\dll

I can do manually, for each folder, but if I have so much files I don't want to do that manually.

[What I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UudM0.png)

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MSBuild Arguments to achieve this. Just add the OutDir argument to the Build Solution Step like this:

```
/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)
```

[image]

In this case, all of your files will end up in the Binaries Directory of your Build Agent. e.g. "C:\Agent1_work\1\b"

Of course you could also use a different target folder than whats inside the variable `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [**Copy File**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) step after the VS Build step. And in the Copy File step, set like the picture below: the Contents could be `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\*.dll` and make sure that the **Flatten Folders** is checked.

[image]

**Note:**
The Flatten Folders only exists in **TFS 2017 Update1** and upper version for on-premises. VSTS also has it. But in TFS 2017 and TFS 2015, it doesn't have.

So, if you are using lower version of TFS, you need to use 2 Copy File steps and copy the 2 dlls to the Main Folder separately. Or you could download the latest source code(it has the FlattenFolder option) of that step from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/CopyFiles). Then package it and upload to your TFS as a custom build step.